# Subfolders and packages when using Appengine and Go

Tags: google-app-engine, go

When deploying and/or testing a Go project for appengine, the appcfg.py and dev_appserver.py tools are used to compile the project

That works fine when all the *.go files are in one folder, but how can a project be be compiled when code is divided into subfolders- yet also need to access functions and constants from eachother?

In Go- subfolders are by definition package boundaries, and I can't see a way to allow the appengine tools to compile multiple packages before testing or deploying, from one project.

Advice on how to tackle this- other than keeping it all in one folder, is appreciated. Even if the solution is to approach it one package (folder) at a time, advice on how to structure that for quick iteration on one project that uses all those packages is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic here. Just make sure each of your go files is placed in a folder and not in the root of your appengine project.

For example:

```
-[Project root]
    app.yaml
    -[packagea]
        packagea.go
        -[packageab]
            packageab.go
    -[packageb]
            packageb.go
```

In the example above, package declarations should be as follows:

- packagea.go:

  ```
  package packagea
  ```
- packageab.go

  ```
  package packageab
  ```
- packageb.go

  ```
  package packageb
  ```

And for example if `packageb` uses both `packagea` and `packageab`, import them as:

- packageb.go:

  ```
  import (
      "packagea"
      "packagea/packageab"
  )
  ```

**Note:**

Note that you cannot create an import cycle (e.g. `packagea` imports `packageb`, and `packageb` imports `packagea`):

[Spec: Import declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations)

> An import declaration declares a dependency relation between the importing and imported package. It is illegal for a package to import itself, directly or indirectly.

You have to structure your code and packages to avoid import cycles or your code will not compile.

Comment: trying to get this to work... no luck so far. if packagea is empty, would the import in packageb for packageab still be packagea/packageb?

Comment: @davidkomer Yes, the import still must be `packagea/packageab` if the file is under the folder `packagea/packageab` inside the project.